# Including a Java .class file in IntelliJ project

Tags: java, class, methods, intellij-idea, dependencies

PREFACE: I realize there are a lot of other threads that ask a similar question about using .class files as a library for a project, I'm still stuck after going through this about 10 different ways.

The project: My teacher gave us .class files (NOT A JAR) that have methods we need to use in the program that *we* write. One of the files is a Book object, and the other has a static method called LoadBooks() that allows the user to enter info about a book and it stores it in an array.

The issue: When I originally made an array of Book objects, IDEA assumed I was trying to use the Java library that already exists, and made an import statement at the top for something like `.print.Book;`. I eventually learned that it was wrong and deleted that statement, leaving my Book array marked incorrect, and my LoadBooks() method call incorrect as well.

My attempts: I read all over about adding dependencies to modules and whatnot... but I've tried so many different ways and nothing is working. I just now made a new project in IDEA and copied over *my* program to start over. I downloaded a fresh copy of my teacher's .class files and left them in the unzipped folder they came in. I then went into Project Structure > Modules > My_Project and added the unzipped file as a Java library. I checked the box that appears next to the new "My_Project Classes" and pressed OK on the Project Structures box.

Now the Book object is okay, and the LoadBooks() method call is still not recognized. I'm to the point where I need a step-by-step explanation.
PLEASE do not link me to some JavaDocs, because I've read them and am just too new to this for it to be helpful.

EDIT: Here's the error message when I compile:

```
Error:(32, 17) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method LoadBooks()
  location: class Project8_Mazzone
```

Comment: ...can you share the latest compiler (error) message, please?

Comment: Error:(32, 17) java: cannot find symbol  
  symbol:   method LoadBooks()  
  location: class Project8_Mazzone

Comment: ... and maybe paste the (line of) invocation of `LoadBooks()`? ..thx!

Comment: Here you go: http://gyazo.com/d87796aa512adcf5cc4321d384f3c0e7

Comment: ..sorry, i cannot view that (a register button, and a broken image), feel free to update your question (you can also include images)

Comment: But long story..., is it maybe that you use (just) `LoadBooks()`, where you instead should use `Book.LoadBooks()`?? (..the next possible would be a spelling (upper/lower case) issue)

Comment: When I called the method I simply typed LoadBooks();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75947/discussion-between-mazzone-and-xerx593).